# Proxy on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, proxy

The goal is to have Ubuntu machine act as a proxy for another machine on WAN. What is the simplest way to accomplish that?

To explain in more detail: There are two machines on the same WAN, but one of them can access the Internet and another one can't. It's possible to talk from one machine to another, though. So the point is to set up the proxy server on the Internet-able machine (having Ubuntu installed).

Note: This is not about using one machine as the bridge on the same LAN, that can be done easily, this is a different approach (as i understand it).

Comment: let me know if the machine which you want to act as a proxy for another machine has direct connection or itself behind another proxy?

Comment: It is a direct connection there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very easy solution is to install a Proxy server package, such as polipo.  For a single machine serving internet to one other device that is probably all you need to do.

`sudo apt-get install polipo`

Then just configure the polipo service to allow connections from the other device, for example un-comment and change the following lines in the `/etc/polipo/config` file:

`proxyAddress = "0.0.0.0"`

`allowedClients = 192.168.56.0/24`

Then restart the polipo server to update its configuration:

`sudo /etc/init.d/polipo restart`

The more complicated part is to convince your other device(s) to use the polipo proxy server.  Setting a proxy depends entirely on the software on the non-directly connected machine.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario involved the same thing with the only exception that the other machine (needing internet) was an Android tablet in my case. I used iptables for routing. It is an easy and out-of-the-box solution on Ubuntu/Debian platforms. Here is a sample routing script that you can run on the internet-enabled machine:

```
#Instead of ppp0, use the interface you use to access the internet
#Instead of wlan0, use the interface connected to your "internet-needy" machine
#####Enable Forwarding:
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

###########Create NAT rules using IPTables
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat -F
iptables --table nat -X
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
###########

#Allow through firewall
iptables -A OUTPUT --out-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT --in-interface wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

Once you run this script, your ubuntu machine acts as a router between the internet-needy machine and the internet, forwarding the internet packets to and fro between them.

Just keep in mind that routing happens at a much lower level than proxying and thus is better in performance. The only disadvantage is that you can't do such things as filter out content or user-authentication based on the proxy client. However, if you just want internet-sharing with good performance, I recommend this method.